# How to mimic iOS upgrade?

Tags: ios, ios10

I have a production bug in my iOS app. I'm having trouble reproducing that. I suspect it to be an Apple bug and it's related with an iOS upgrade. Is there a way to mimic an iOS upgrade?

I tried an approach with following steps:

1. compile the app on a device with old OS version
2. download app container in Xcode=>Window=>Devices
3. compile the app on a device with the new OS version
4. replace app container with the one from the old OS version

Not sure this is effective to mimic OS upgrade though.

Buying lots of devices with older OS version and upgrading them doesn't seem to be scalable...

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why you need to mimic iOS update. You can test on devices which run different version of iOS.

Comment: @sahara108 thanks for your comment. All bug reports come from the latest iOS version and they all had the app installed before the OS was upgraded. No fresh install could reproduce after a quite large number of attempts. So the suspect is that the upgrade is doing something that cause the problem.